# Elementary function producing primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, closed-form, elementary-functions

I know there is no known [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(n)$ is the $n$-th prime number, but is there a proof for the non-existance of one? How about one which only takes values from the primes on inputs from $\mathbb{N}$, with infinitely many primes in its image?

Comment: As far as I know, the "elementary" function exists,.but just is not useful.

Comment: @lonestudent What do you mean by not useful? Which elementry function is that?

Comment: To be clear, an elementary function is something built out of polynomials, exponentials, and logarithms yes?

Comment: If you consider the floor function to be elementary, see this page: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html. It gives some answers to your second question whose definitions you can extend to the whole of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Paul's suggestion source is useful. You can check.

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary"? Riemann's explicit formula is simple but maybe not what you'd call elementary?

Comment: The point is that there is no known function that allows us to efficiently compute the $n$-th prime number for large $n$, for example the $10^{100}$ th prime number. Whether the prime formulas known are "elementary" depends on the definition of "elementary".

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Yes, I mean [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)

Comment: @Peter A bit off-topic and speculative, but I wonder if there's a quantum algorithm capable of generating the $n^{th}$ prime.

Comment: @StevenClark I am not even convinced of the Shor algorithm that is claimed to allow efficient factorization with a quantum computer. I am not an expert however in quantum computers. Peter Ripota claimed in one of his writings that they are purely fictive anyway. I cannot judge whether he is right.